# How to convert delimited string into multi-dimensional array with associative keys?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, delimiter, explode

Can anyone help with this regular expression please?

Here's an example string I'm trying to convert into php array.

`$str="hopOptions:hops hopOptions:salmonSafe region:domestic region:specialty region:imported"`

And I need the final aray to be:

```
$filters = array (
    "hopOptions"  => array("hops", "salmonSafe"),
    "region"      => array("domestic", "specialty", "imported")
);
```

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster is to avoid regex and use two explode calls:

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5288e9f9eca696246bf09fbf2c2d690bca272191)

Code:

```
$str = "hopOptions:hops hopOptions:salmonSafe region:domestic region:specialty region:imported";
foreach(explode(' ',$str) as $pair){
    $x=explode(':',$pair);
    $result[$x[0]][]=$x[1];
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Or with regex...

[PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/179af47a4685f5188d87ab8232233b674f820e90)

Code:

```
$str = "hopOptions:hops hopOptions:salmonSafe region:domestic region:specialty region:imported";
if(preg_match_all('/([^ ]+):([^ ]+)/',$str,$out)){
    foreach($out[1] as $i=>$v){
        $result[$v][]=$out[2][$i];
    }
    var_export($result);
}else{
    echo "no matches";
}
```

Comment: @VadimGoncharov Is there a possibility of any spaces in your values?  This would be relevant information for your question.

Comment: yeah theach item in string will be separated by a space, but that's it for spaces.

Comment: Im going to pick this as the answer as it uses regex. But I do realize I could have just used php array functions to achive similar results. Thanks @mickamackusa

Comment: I'll use the explode version for this for now..I like the sound of faster

Comment: @VadimGoncharov Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know php and came up with this. Hope there's better way.

```
$str = "hopOptions:hops hopOptions:salmonSafe region:domestic region:specialty region:imported";

// it creates an array of pairs
$ta = array_map(function($s) {return explode(":", $s);}, explode(" ", $str));

// this loop converts the paris into desired form
$filters = array();
foreach($ta as $pair) {
    if (array_key_exists($pair[0], $filters)) {
        array_push($filters[$pair[0]], $pair[1]);
    }
    else {
        $filters[$pair[0]] = array($pair[1]);
    }
}

print_r($filters);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [hopOptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => hops
            [1] => salmonSafe
        )

    [region] => Array
        (
            [0] => domestic
            [1] => specialty
            [2] => imported
        )

)
```